# Argument Error: Unknown key: :from

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create messages in rails. But when I run Message.new in the rails console I get:

`ArgumentError: Unknown key: :from. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate ... etc`

My setup is as follows:

User Model

```
  has_many :messages
  has_many :message_recipients, :as => :recipient, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :received_messages, :through => :message_recipients
```

Message Model

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :message_recipients, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :recipients, :through => :message_recipients, :class_name => "User", :from => :recipient
```

Message_Recipient Model

```
  belongs_to :message
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :recipient_id
```

Thanks for any advice or help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that `:from` is not a valid option in this line:

```
has_many :recipients, :through => :message_recipients, :class_name => "User", :from => :recipient
```

You should just be able to remove that part.

For valid options, see the documentation for [`has_many`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many).

**UPDATE**

In the syntax of this line, the `:from` is a key in the options hash of the `has_many` macro/method. But the `has_many` method is checking the passed in options and warning you if anything you pass in is unknown. That's what `:from` would be -- an unknown option. I.e. Rails has no idea what to do with it. So it's not valid and just shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Message` model, while defining has_many association with `recipients`, you have passed `:from` option which is not a valid key for `has_many` method which is why you receive the error as

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :from. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate ... etc
```

In `Message` model

```
has_many :recipients, :through => :message_recipients, :class_name => "User", 
         :from => :recipient
         ## ^^ 
         ## Remove this
```

Here is a reference of all the valid options which you can pass to **[has_many association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many-label-Options)**

Answer (score 0):

**:from** is not a valid option in has_many relationship used in Message model. That's why you are receiving the problem of **Argument Error.**